# large value for null variance and residual variance in logical regression

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I am new in R language.I am using R to do logical regression to a dataset to predict the risk of heart disease.
I have created a binomial model with glm and again created the model after removing the insignificant variables.
Then I created the predict model and generated the confusion matrix.

1.The Null variance and Residual Variance values are very large in this result .Found that when these values are small it will predict the results well.How can I reduce it?

2.What all details I can conclude from my confusion matrix.Is this a good one.

#checking Logistic Model with all the variables

```
?glm()
logistic_model <- glm(TenYearCHD~., data = train_heart_data, family = "binomial")
summary(logistic_model)
```

[image]

```
#Logistic Model after removing insignificant variables
logistic_model <- glm(TenYearCHD~. -education -diabetes -diaBP -heartRate -currentSmoker -prevalentHyp -BMI
                      , data = train_heart_data, family = "binomial")
summary(logistic_model)
```

[image]

```
#Predicting TenYearCHD on test data
pred_model <- predict(logistic_model,newdata = test_heart_data[,-16],type = "response")
summary(pred_model)

# Selecting threshold 0.5
pred_test_data <- ifelse(pred_model>0.5,1,0)
summary(pred_test_data)
#Creating confusion matrix 
confusion_matrix <- table(pred_test_data,test_heart_data$TenYearCHD)
```

## Calculating Accuracy with threshold 0.5

confusionMatrix(confusion_matrix)
[image]

Comment: it is the **deviance** not variance. When you run a logistic regression, these values are derived from -2* log likelihood of the model... It's dependent on the number of observations you have and don't interpret it like that

Comment: maybe check out something like https://bookdown.org/egarpor/SSS2-UC3M/logreg-deviance.html or you can calculate a pseudo R^2 (which I don't quite use so can't comment)

Comment: Regarding the confusion matrix, one important question to answer is: what is the event rate in your modeling data? Is it 50%? If not, you should consider using another threshold when creating the confusion matrix, and start analyzing the results when the threshold is set equal to the event rate in your data.